# Customizing image in Custom TableView

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, uikit

I want to add a corner radius to my image that is nested inside a custom cell, inside a custom table view using Swift in Xcode.  Here is my code.  Does anyone know how to apply `.cornerRadius = 10`?

```
struct Beer {
    let title: String
    let imageName: String
}

//Enter cell lines here for new beers
let data: [Beer] = [
    Beer(title: "Helles Half Life", imageName: "HellesHalfLife"),
    Beer(title: "Racemic Red Ale", imageName: "RedAle"),
    Beer(title: "RSIPA", imageName: "RSIPA"),
    Beer(title: "Stage II HAC", imageName: "HellesHalfLife"),
    Beer(title: "Helleva Stage II Lager", imageName: "HellevaStageII"),
    Beer(title: "Train of Four Stout", imageName: "TrainOfFour"),
    Beer(title: "Patrick's Feeling Hazy", imageName: "PatricksFeelingHazy"),
    Beer(title: "BIS 40", imageName: "BIS40"),
    Beer(title: "40 Winks", imageName: "FortyWinks"),
    Beer(title: "", imageName: ""),
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Beer = data[indexPath.row]
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as!     TableViewCell
    cell.label.text = Beer.title
    cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: Beer.imageName)
   return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->
CGFloat{
return 120
    }
```

I tried adding `table.layer.cornerRadius = 10` in the `override func viewDidLoad()` section under `table.delegate`.

Comment: The code to customize the image view belongs in your `TableViewCell` class, not in any of the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

in your TableViewCell Class File,

```
iconImageView.clipsToBounds = true
iconImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

or you can also add cornerRadius in cellForRowAt:

```
cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: Beer.imageName)
cell.iconImageView.clipsToBounds = true
cell.iconImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add imageview inside a view and then

```
cell.yourImageViewContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
cell.yourImageViewContainerView.clipsToBounds = true
```

or

```
cell.yourImageViewContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
cell.yourImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```